# random server timeout connections

Tags: centos, tcp

I am searching for a solution for this issue for 2 days now. I have a centos server, and I get random timeout connections error, about 10-20% of the times.

yesterday it happened to one of my users, he did a reset to his modem and computer and problem was gone. this morning I started getting this issue.

I have no reputation here, I can't post images, so I will put links instead.

Here is what I discovered so far:

[image]

The application on my computer sends a TCP SYN packet to the server. On good connection, the server returns an ack. On the bad connections, even after retransmission attempts, no ack is received.

The second issue that I have seen is that when I run tcpdump on my server to my ip, it looks as if the server has gone totally crazy. I see hundreds of what seems to be ask packets every second. It is an endless stream of packets.

[image]

I checked the ip of other users, and it seems ok, so it only happens to me right now.

Up until a week ago, everything was ok. I am not a linux expert, I would be happy for any suggestions of what I should do here.

Comment: You forgot to exclude your own ssh traffic from your tcpdump, so it is showing you all the packets from your own ssh connection to the server while tcpdump is running.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michael. this is the command that I run from my server: "tcpdump dst host X_IP_X -tttt". When the ip was my computer, I got hundreds of packets per seconds, when it was of other person, it was relatively quiet. In addition, I didn't expect any packets between my computer and the server, because my computer wasn't even connected at the time

Comment: A retransmission is either : service wasnt able to process the packet, server wasnt able to compute anything or a physical link error. For the first 2, please use top to be sure the cpu usage is ok. At 100% you can have issue like that.

Comment: Thanks for you help Michael and yagmoth. I solved it. Michael, you were right (of course) about the ssh, I completely forgot that I had putty connected to the server. Add it as an answer and I will credit you for it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . At least in my case, all I did was reset the router on my computer, and the problem disappeared.

I have read on the internet many suggestions to change server's tcp/ip parameters. So if this happens to you, before you do anything, I suggest that you check your hardware as well.

The issue with the hundreds of packets that I saw on tcpdump between my server and my IP is the result of the terminal program that I used on my computer to connect to the server. Of course that it is completely ok.

To filter ssh port that is used by the terminal, use this command:

```
 tcpdump dst host YOU.R00.IP0.000 -tttt and src port not 22
```